# What is the difference between a Name Server and a DNS Server?

Tags: dns, dhcp, windows-server-2008

Similar questions have been asked and answered with a treatise on network topologies. I do have networking experience, and I am hoping to get more to the point in my explanation. I was configuring DHCP server on a Microsoft 2008 server. There is a scope option "005 Name Servers" followed by "006 DNS Servers." Both allow a list of IPv4 addresses as the data. My assistant asked what the difference was, and I did not know what to tell him. So, I am asking... what is the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/320042/955407

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Domain Name Server and Name Server the same thing?](https://superuser.com/questions/320042/are-domain-name-server-and-name-server-the-same-thing)

Comment: @Ramhound: After reading the actual question, it doesn't look like a duplicate at all. The answer about general terminology does not apply to DHCP option names, and in this case would be outright wrong.

Answer (score 6):

According to IANA's [DHCP options registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xhtml), option 5 is for specifying an **[IEN-116](https://www.rfc-editor.org/ien/ien116.txt)** protocol name server – which is an early precursor to DNS, also called the [ARPA Host Name Server Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPA_Host_Name_Server_Protocol).

*(IENs (Internet Experiment Notes) were documents similar to RFCs. For example, before the TCP/IPv4 RFCs were released, there were IENs written about TCPv3, TCPv2, and so on.)*

There *is* an option for WINS, but that's option 44 "NETBIOS Name Servers".